# Calculating difference of rows grouped by another row in r

Tags: r

I have a `date`, a `package_id` and a `location_id` in three columns.

Let us suppose that the the following observations happen:

```
packake_id location_id date_id
PACK001    100         2018-04-02
PACK001    101         2018-04-06
PACK002    102         2018-04-12
PACK002    103         2018-04-15
PACK002    101         2018-04-20
```

It means that PACK001 arrived to location 100 on 2018-04-02, and arrived to location 101 on 2018-04-06. 
Likewise, PACK002 arrived to location 102 on 2018-04-12, then to location 103 on 2018-04-15, then to location 101 on 2018-04-20.

I would like to add a column `days` that says how many days passed per package in a location. In the example it should be like this:

```
packake_id location_id days
PACK001       100       4
PACK002       102       3
PACK002       103       5
```

Thanks for your help. I found ways to calculate differences but it is different because it is not a linear calculation because these are somewhat grouped by the package id so a consecutive subtraction of date_ids are wrong.

Comment: where is location 101?

Comment: The expected output is not in sync with the suggested input. See also @Sotos

Comment: the data is unclear. What is the location variable? Why the number of days for PACK001 and location 100 is 4? This should be the case only if the second line of your data has also a location of 100.

Comment: The date shows when the package arrived to a location. So in the example the package was from 2018-04-02 to 2018-04-06 in location 100. That is 4 days.
Then is was moved to location 101, until we have no info on the next location, there is no data for it.

Comment: I updated the question but all the data was consistent in it. Thanks.

Comment: I understand, but the data you provide are not correct. e.g. location_id 103, occurs once in the input. This cannot yield a duration.

Comment: I disagree, it is correct. It tracks the arrivals only.